# Open files in spark with given timestamp

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, timestamp, hdfs

I use newAPIHadoopFile in my scala class to read text files from HDFS as below

```
val conf = new SparkConf
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hc = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
val dataFilePath = "/data/sample"
val input = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(dataFilePath, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], hc)
```

But now I just need to open files within a range of timestamp.
Any idea on how I could do that?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files contain timestamp directly in filename, it's pretty easy:

```
val path = "/hdfs/some_dir/2016-07-*/*" 
val data = sqlContext.jsonFile(data) // or textFile e.g.
data.count() // number of rows in all files matching pattern
```

This will read all dirs July of 2016 and all files in those dirs. You can do pattern matching even on filenames, e.g. `val path = "/hdfs/some_dir/2016-07-01/file-*.json"`

Is this helpful or you are looking for system timestamps filtering?

---

**Edit:**
In case you need to filter using system timestamp:

```
val path = "/hdfs/some_dir/"
val now: Long = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
var files = new java.io.File(path).listFiles.filter(_.lastModified >= now)
```

Or you can construct more complex date filtering like selecting date in a "human" way. It should be easy now.

Comment: Thank you Cimox for your answer. I'm looking for a system timestamp filter.

Comment: I edited mine post, with the code above you should be able to filter files with given timestamp. You can afterwards open these filtered files using Spark.

Comment: Jeff please could you mark as solved/add upvote? :) I am trying to gain some positive reputation so I can comment more posts here at stackoverflow :). Thank you